# Managing Memory

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, memory, hook

Hi first question on this website, young developer working on a project for uni and I have decided to build an Application Launcher in C# which index's exe's within directories specified by the user! My problem is that i'm using a Keyboard Hook to allow the user to call the application to focus when required, looking at the task manager whilst the applications binary(exe) is in memory, everytime i call the application to focus using Alt + X the memory in the **"Private Working Set" (PWS)** starts off around 40,000k (already to large so this is cause for concern) but then once the application loses focus and I call it to focus again the PWS' memory will rise to 50,000k and will raise by 10,000k every time i repeat this...

I understand that i am probably not disposing all objects in a correct manor, I have visually added table adapters to this form for interactions with the SQL database to which I have disposed and set to null (don't know if i'm meant to do both) and called the garbage collector.. Basically what I would like answered is what are the best tools to find memory leaks and how can i keep a form in memory but have it consume the least amount of resources as possible also why is my application basically adding 10,000k to the PWS each time the application is brought to focus, is it basically creating a new instance of the form each time? I am going to add a mutex class to prevent multiple instances anyway but would this solve my problem?

I understand that this is probably a rookie question but this is the first time that memory management issues have been required for me to look into...

Thanks in advance

**Update:** Hi guys, just in case anyone stumbles upon this thread and finds that this is somewhat relevant i have found that my problem didn't exactly require a fix or in fact contain a leak. After installing my application and launching it i got the application to its peak memory usage and kept Task Manager open to monitor its memory, turns out that the Garbage Collector does eventually do it's job although it can take 2/3 minutes.

Peak Memory: 200,000k which is incredibly high for the scale of the application once the GC had done its work it dropped right down to 3,000k..

Comment: It does sound like you might some problems. For one you never need to manually call the garbage collector.  This question has some usefull information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573167/memory-management-in-net

Comment: Please try to change Alt + X to another character like Alt + T and tell us if you still have the same result.

Comment: @MohammedShraim changed and still have the same problem, will check your link now asawyer. I know that i dont have to call the garbage collector manually, this was me just trying to find a work-around (not a good one at that).

Comment: @NathanSmith It's impossible to tell from here if you have a memory leak or not really. Basically the CLR can use as much memory as it wants. Without memory pressure, why take the time to run the gc? *The fastest code is always the code you never run*.

Comment: @asawyer it was silly to call the gc to be fair as it will dispose of all objects not being used once it passes! The thing i cant understand is why its using more and more memory as i bring it to focus? This is the main problem! If you could help me with this i would be eternally grateful.

Comment: @NathanSmith I don't exactly have your project in front of me to run do I? Grab one of the many free c# profiling tools out there, and see what it says. Without any other information It's impossible to say.

Comment: @NathanSmith Here's another good article on CLR memory management: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that just because the memory footprint is going up doesn't mean that you have a memory leak (although you might).  C# will only run the garbage collector occasionally, or when it needs memory because it is running out.  If manually calling the garbage collector makes the memory go away then it means that you don't have a memory leak, but rather the garbage collector simply isn't bothering to clear up the memory yet.  If running it doesn't help, then it means it can't clear up the memory and you may have a problem.

Comment: Yeah, as when i continually bring and remove app from focus to see how high it'll go before it crashes which will vary depending on the computer's specs, it starts the application not responding window. Which i imagine shows that the gc isn't clearing up the memory, do you reckon the keyboard hook could have something to do with it? Thanks

Comment: @NathanSmith Neither Servy or myself have Ramond Chen's physic debugging powers. Please post the relevant code *after* you run the profiler I previously mentioned. Then we will have something we can help you with.

Comment: Without any access to code it's really hard to say.  I'd suggest using a profiler to see what's taking up so much of the memory.  Visual Studio has one built in (if you have certain licence versions).  That should at least give you an idea of where to start looking.

Comment: @Servy thanks servy, i've got ultimate so running profiling now!

Comment: @Servy It seems that i have a leak in unmanaged code, from what i gather this can be caused by importing dll's that have been poorly constructed or written in c/c++? I'm using Telerik's WinForms, Twitterizer and Newtonsoft dll's.. Could this be the cause of the problem, although the twitterizer dll isn't in use on the form that seems to contain the leak. Any words of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @NathanSmith Probably not disposing of a nonmanaged resource somewhere. I still see no code posted though, so with my magic crystal ball, I say the problem is on line 395.

Comment: @asawyer still trying to narrow it down, dont want to copy and paste my whole solution... Thanks though!